# Windows 7 permission issue

Tags: windows-7

I just freshly installed Windows 7 (32bit) and I have an issue.

I want to edit the details of a file:
[image]

It keeps saying I need the permission from the admin. I tried editing the security tab as posted somewhere else, but it keeps saying I need permission.

Comment: Are you an Admin in the system? Also what details of that file are you trying to edit?

Comment: "Are the an Admin in the system?"  you mean if there is an admin on the system!? or that I am the admin? I would say I am the admin, but I dont know how that works on windows 7, I dont use it alot....
+ all the details I can change.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen When you login to the computer, do you do it as an administrator or as another user?

Comment: it logs in automaticly, and I dont use any passwords, is that the issue? if thats so, thats really weird.

Comment: Try this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) and download the registry key from there and let see if its helped out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are an admin of the system, you should take ownership of the file first. Here's a guide that can help you do that:

http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm

After that you shouldn't have any problems with permission.

Comment: However its not good to just link the answer to somewhere with an article on web. You should post the steps here with details.

Comment: this was the guide I tried, and nope, its not working, thanks for posting/making but it isnt working, same error.
isnt there a mod for windows to just let it shut up, I really dont care if its a security flaw, as long as I can do whatever I want.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the below steps:**

Considerations: I am having my file named `temp.txt`, and I *logged-in* with `Administrator` privileges.

**1.** Right-Click on the file > Properties > Security Tab

[image]

**2.** Click on `Advance` button > Owner Tab

[image]

**3.** Click on `Edit` button, if prompt, enter the admin password or just Yes.

[image]

**4.** Select *your-name* account as the *owner* of file and click on `Apply` > `Ok` > `Ok`

Now Again go to `Security` tab as in step - *1*, Click on `Edit` button.

[image]

Set Focus on *your-account-name* and *Check* the `Full Control` checkbox, click `Ok` > `Ok`

And you are all set to go now.

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: this was the guide I tried, and nope, its not working, thanks for posting/making but it isnt working, same error.

Comment: isnt there a mod for windows to just let it shut up, I really dont care if its a security flaw, as long as I can do whatever I want.

Comment: Then i must ask you, _what file/folder you are trying to access?_ because some files/folders do not have any privileges rather than OS(System) itself, and it does not provide `ownership` of this to any other account type..

Comment: I just downloaded the file. And I want to edit the details, because they arent fitting.

Comment: Well may be its _file-level_ security be there, if it is not a personal document than can you please provide me the download link, i would like to test it by my own..

Comment: try this: http://bit.ly/LRLnUx
I shortend the url for you

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen sorry friend i got a `Running OS not supported` error, i guess it did not support `64bit` OS..

Comment: just edit the details xD?! I installed 32 bits windows only for that program (btw deleting the link)