# Break Folder Protection, Folder Guard Lock or Folder in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

When I'm making a new partition by the partition magic, suddenly blackout happen. And because my computer isnt equipped with UPS (uninterruptible Power Supply), my computer finally died, too. When power is restored, I tried to turn on the computer. Suddenly my computer can not boot normally into windows. Option through safemode and others all I've tried. The result fails, can not boot at all although through safe mode. i wonder it happen because partition Magic did not finish the work and stopped in the middle of the process and cause the transfer of data files stopped, finally any default files in windows was disappear.

After that, I take my hard drive to a friend.Hope i can save some important data,and could make fresh windows again.

When I tried to read the hard drive in windows explorer,some of my data cannot opened because it needs administrator privilages or the original user's default start my windows (my computer).it seems similar with how Folder Guard works.

how do i solve this uncommon issues ?

Comment: why dont you give us some screen shot, just wanna make it clear with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

On your friend's PC, try accessing the folders by taking the `ownership` of folders. My [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/435349/139215) explain this process in detail.

Also you download [this `.reg`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CFcQFjAC&url=http://www.hack7mc.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=14&ei=jlnfT4mhOYXUrQeT9eTIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEvjFYoKZdFJfgi5GZLcqjyZkmHkQ) file for a `registry` hack that can [bring `Take Ownership`](http://www.askvg.com/add-take-ownership-option-in-file-folder-context-menu-in-windows-vista/) option in folder(s) and file(s) context menu.